# Aplication on default page- tomcat/java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jsp-tags

I want to set the context root, so that after I type in my browser IP:8080 my tomcat site must show my application. 
Now I create index.jsp in /webapps/ROOT
and type in this file:

```
< %@ page import="java.util.List" %>

< %@ page  import="package1.Aplikacja" %>
```

in /webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/ I have file: web.xml
in /webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/package1   I have  files: Aplikacja.class plikacja.java

So how can I now run this application on my IP:8080 page?
I have imported the class, but how can I run it?

Comment: never System.exit(1); !!! use response.sendError() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define mapping between your servlet (Aplikacja) and urls in your web.xml

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Twoja App</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Aplikacja</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>package1.Aplikacja</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Aplikacja</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and you can access your servlet by:

```
localhost:8080/app
```

(if you placed all the files correctly under the ROOT folder).

If you change servlet-mapping to * all the request will be handled by your Aplikacja

Normally you don't want all the requests going through one servlet, in such a case you define normal mapping ie /app and create index.html which redirects to the "default" servlet:

```
<html>
<head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/app">
 </head>
</html>
```

You should probably use some IDE to build a proper webapp which is bundled into a .war file instead of placing the files manually under tomcat.

Comment: as I wrote, change the mapping to * or use the index.html with redirect

Comment: Last question. Now is good! Thanks a lot! You're rly good! But... 
I changed in your version web.xml (/app) to (/). 
Now IP:8080  show my application
Now IP:8080/test and other /words  show my application.
Is good! But i need 1 change more. 
Tell me where i can set, that only IP:8080/help will show to help.html file?

Comment: make subfolder help and place there help.html

Comment: Thanks Zielu for help. All works how must work! 
Last configuration of my apache/tomcat's which i cant set i will describe in new post, here is another topic, if you will have little time please lot there ;) THANKS BRO !:)